# Why does APT keep saying the gcloud SDK doesnt exist?

Tags: gcloud, apt

Apt cant find the sdk even though im doing the command correctly

I have done all the commands your supposed to do before the install correctly

Why doesnt apt install google-cloud-sdk work

Im in the root user

Turns out all i needed to do was run apt update

Comment: Few questions here if you are still finding this issue. What document are you following to achieve this? Are you using the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get)? Also, what do you mean with "Why doesnt apt install google-cloud-sdk work" how is not working? Don't tell us what is not doing, instead share with us what is the current state, what error message are you getting? Also where are you trying to install the Gcloud SDK, Ubuntu, MacOs...?

Comment: i was tryimg to imstall gcloud SDK on Ubuntu using APT and it said it doesnt exist. i do know that APT gets most of its packages from my VPS host, digitalocean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the google cloud sdk in the $PATH?
type echo $PATH
If the sdk isn't in the path then it won't find it, it may be that your root user has a different path than the user you used to set up the sdk

hope that helps